# .Net Core auto-generated string primary key

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, primary-key, autogeneratecolumn

.Net Core 2.2 Identity framework has string primary key which is an auto-generated GUID. My question is how to have an auto-generated STRING primary key using Entity Framework 2.2?

Comment: like generate a random string without any constraints (any length, any characters, etc)?

Comment: GUID but the type must be string. Not Guid.

Comment: Why do you want to have a property of type `string`  instead of type `Guid` if you know/want the value to be a valid GUID?

Comment: I need a generic auto-generated VARCHAR primary key. GUID is a good fit but I don't want to limit to GUID type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have the attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` added to the column. See the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generation-patterns) for more details.

Comment: This does the trick: 
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public string ID { get; set; }

Answer (score 4):

Auto-generated primary key by using Fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Node>().Property(x => x.ID).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
}
```